# Guardar dos valores y dos puntuaciones en localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría guardar dos nombres introducidos y sus dos puntuaciones en localstorage y solo consigo hacerlo de uno solo. No se si se realiza con JSON porque soy muy principiante por eso disculpad mi inexperiencia. La idea es guardar name1 con su puntuación suma1 y name2 con su puntuación suma2. La puntuación no he conseguido hacerlo por eso no coloco ese código. Dejo el poco que he hecho (llamo en ese lugar a las funciones para ir probando):

```
function saveNames() {
    localStorage.setItem('nomUsuari', name1);
    localStorage.setItem('nomUsuari2', name2);
}   

function obtener() {
    var nombreGuardado = localStorage.getItem('nomUsuari');
    var nombreGuardado2 = localStorage.getItem('nomUsuari2');
}

var name1 = prompt("Nombre jugador uno");


var name2 = prompt("Nombre jugador dos");
saveNames();
obtener();

var cards = new Array(
    new Array("manzana", 1),
    new Array("manzana", 2),
    new Array("manzana", 3), 
    new Array("pera", 1),
    new Array("pera", 2),
    new Array("pera", 3),
    new Array("melon", 1),
    new Array("melon", 2),
    new Array("melon", 3)
);

var cards_views_ids1 = Array();
var cards_views_ids2 = Array();
var suma = 0;
var suma1 = 0;
var suma2 = 0;

function random_card(num){
    if(cards.length >0 ){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
        var palos = "<br>Palo: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
        var numero = cards[rand][1];
        document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += palos;
        document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += numero;

        var repetido = 0;

        switch(num) {
            case 1:
            suma1++;
            suma = suma1;
            cards_views_ids1.push(numero);     

            cards_views_ids1.forEach(function(dato){
                if (dato == numero){
                    repetido++;
                  }
            });
            break;
            case 2:
            suma2++;
            suma = suma2;
            cards_views_ids2.push(numero);

            cards_views_ids2.forEach(function(dato){
                if (dato == numero){
                  repetido++;
                 }
           });
           break;
    }  

 if(repetido == 2){
    const buttons=document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    buttons[num-1].setAttribute('disabled','disabled')

    setTimeout(function(){
        var jugador = document.getElementById("player"+num+"_result");
        if (jugador.innerHTML == "0"){
              var puntua ='Se repitió el valor <br> fruta: ' + cards[rand][0] +
              ' - Valor: ' +    cards[rand][1] +'. Se extrayeron ' + suma +
              ' valores hasta encontrar el valor repetido.';
              jugador.innerHTML=puntua;

        }

      }, 100);  

  }

}

}


 <div id="start_form"></div>
 <div id="div1"></div>
 <div id="div2"></div>
 <div id="game_main">

 <div id="boton"><button onclick="random_card(1);">Extraer</button>
 <span id="player1"></span></div><span id="player1_result">0</span>
 <div id="boton2"><button onclick="random_card(2);">Extraer</button>
 <span id="player2"></span></div><span id="player2_result">0</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo primero, dices que no se guarda más que un nombre pero no es así, con tu código ya se están guardando los dos :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respecto a guardar la suma, una opción sencilla es hacer lo mismo que con los nombres justo cuando asignas el valor a `suma`:

```
 suma = suma2;
 localStorage.setItem('suma2', suma);
```

El valor se actualizará con cada llamada a la función `random_card()`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respecto a guardar la información en un JSON, no sé hasta qué punto necesitas guardar datos. Si son sólo esos campos creo que no te merece la pena complicarte.

Aquí te dejo un [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/rm7Lfkhn/)

Si tienes cualquier duda me dices y actualizo la respuesta ;)

Edito con tu comentario:

Creo que el problema es que por defecto Chrome no tiene desplegado del todo el grid con los valores del `localstorage`, inicialmente se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si despliegas se ven todos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola @Kiko_L !! Mil gracias por tu tiempo y amabilidad!! he tardado en contestar porque en chrome no me sale pero he probado en firefox y me sale como a ti! te pasa lo mismo con el chrome? así ya me va perfecto pero por curiosidad...

Comment: Editada la respuesta, a ver si es eso lo que te pasa :)

Comment: Perfecto! mil gracias kiko!!